# How to prove countably infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove the following set is countably infinite? 
$\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\}$

I know that I can say this set is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite, thus this set is infinite. However, I've not yet proven that the rational numbers are countable, so I'm unsure how to proceed in proving this set countable.

Comment: $\{1\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, is $\{1\}$ infinite?

Comment: Have you defined countable as having a bijection to either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$?  You can then find a bijection from $\mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$ to your set in question.

Comment: You will want to use the countable infinite-ness of $\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If I can show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite, how do I then conclude that this set is also countably infinite?

Comment: What is your definition of countably infinite? It all stems from the definition you're using. If "countably infinite" sets are exactly those in bijection with $\Bbb N$, then a composition of bijections would be useful.

Comment: Notice this difference: $\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ versus $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.  The former, using \backslash, lacks proper spacing; the latter is correct usage and uses \setminus.  \backslash is not intended as a binary operation symbol and so lacks the spacing that comes with those. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: "this set is a subset of $\mathbb Q$, and that $\mathbb Q$ is infinite, thus this set is infinite."  That is incorrect.  Not all subsets of infinite sets are infinite, and in particular, not all subsets of $\mathbb Q$ are infinite. This one is infinite, but you cannot conclude that merely because it is a subset of $\mathbb Q$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-to-one correspondence between the set you consider and the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ of positive integers:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
1, & -1, & 1/2, & -1/2, & 1/3, & -1/3, & 1/4, & -1/4, & \ldots \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \cdots
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

A set X is countably infinite if there exists a bijection between X and $\mathbb{Z}$.

To prove a set is countably infinite, you only need to show that this definition is satisfied, i.e. you need to show there is a bijection between X and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there a bijection between $\left\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a bijection $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and the function $g\colon \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\to\{1/n:n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\}$ defined by $g(n):=1/n$ is a bijection, we know that the composition $g\circ f$ is a bijection, so the set $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\}$ must be countable.

**Remark.** If you have no defined the set $\mathbb Q$, you can prove this statement using the set $\{1\}\times\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. Then, when you have $\mathbb Q$, for instance, you can prove that this sets have the same cardinality with $\{m/n\in\mathbb Q:m=1\}$ which is a subset of $\mathbb Q$.